# Why does my Python loop intends to consume all the memory?

Tags: python

I want to generate and keep a set of tuples in a certain time. Yet I found the program seemed to consume all the memory if given enough time.

I have tried two methods. One is delete the newly generated variables, the other is gc.collect(). But neither of them worked. If I just generate and not keep the tuples, the program would consume limited memory.

generate and keep: gk.py

```
import gc
import time
from memory_profiler import profile
from random import sample
from sys import getsizeof


@profile
def loop(limit):
    t = time.time()
    i = 0
    A = set()
    while True:
        i += 1
        duration = time.time() - t
        a = tuple(sorted(sample(range(200), 100)))
        A.add(a)
        if not i % int(1e4):
            print('step {:.2e}...'.format(i))
        if duration > limit:
            print('done')
            break
        # method 1: delete the variables
#        del duration, a
        # method 2: use gc
#        gc.collect()
    memory = getsizeof(t) + getsizeof(i) + getsizeof(duration) + \
             getsizeof(a) + getsizeof(limit) + getsizeof(A)
    print('memory consumed: {:.2e}MB'.format(memory/2**20))
    pass


def main():
    limit = 300
    loop(limit)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running...')
    main()
```

generate and not keep: gnk.py

```
import time
from memory_profiler import profile
from random import sample
from sys import getsizeof


@profile
def loop(limit):
    t = time.time()
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        duration = time.time() - t
        a = tuple(sorted(sample(range(200), 100)))
        if not i % int(1e4):
            print('step {:.2e}...'.format(i))
        if duration > limit:
            print('done')
            break
    memory = getsizeof(t) + getsizeof(i) + getsizeof(duration) + \
             getsizeof(a) + getsizeof(limit)
    print('memory consumed: {:.2e}MB'.format(memory/2**20))
    pass


def main():
    limit = 300
    loop(limit)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running...')
    main()
```

use "mprof" (needs module memory_profiler) in cmd/shell to check memory usage

```
mprof run my_file.py
mprof plot
```

result of gk.py

```
memory consumed: 4.00e+00MB
Filename: gk.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    12     32.9 MiB     32.9 MiB   @profile
    13                             def loop(limit):
    14     32.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       t = time.time()
    15     32.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       i = 0
    16     32.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       A = set()
    17     32.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       while True:
    18    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           i += 1
    19    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           duration = time.time() - t
    20    115.8 MiB      0.3 MiB           a = tuple(sorted(sample(range(200), 100)))
    21    115.8 MiB      2.0 MiB           A.add(a)
    22    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           if not i % int(1e4):
    23    111.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               print('step {:.2e}...'.format(i))
    24    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           if duration > limit:
    25    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               print('done')
    26    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               break
    27                                     # method 1: delete the variables
    28                             #        del duration, a
    29                                     # method 2: use gc
    30                             #        gc.collect()
    31                                 memory = getsizeof(t) + getsizeof(i) + getsizeof(duration) + \
    32    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB                getsizeof(a) + getsizeof(limit) + getsizeof(A)
    33    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       print('memory consumed: {:.2e}MB'.format(memory/2**20))
    34    115.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       pass
```

result of gnk.py

```
memory consumed: 9.08e-04MB
Filename: gnk.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    11     33.0 MiB     33.0 MiB   @profile
    12                             def loop(limit):
    13     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       t = time.time()
    14     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       i = 0
    15     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       while True:
    16     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           i += 1
    17     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           duration = time.time() - t
    18     33.0 MiB      0.1 MiB           a = tuple(sorted(sample(range(200), 100)))
    19     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           if not i % int(1e4):
    20     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB               print('step {:.2e}...'.format(i))
    21     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           if duration > limit:
    22     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB               print('done')
    23     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB               break
    24                                 memory = getsizeof(t) + getsizeof(i) + getsizeof(duration) + \
    25     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB                getsizeof(a) + getsizeof(limit)
    26     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       print('memory consumed: {:.2e}MB'.format(memory/2**20))
    27     33.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       pass
```

I have two problems:

1. both the programs consumed more memory than the variables occupied. "gk.py" consumed 115.8MB, its variables occupied 4.00MB. "gnk.py" consumed 33.0MB, its variables occupied 9.08e-04MB. Why the programs consumed more memory than the corresponding variables occupied?
2. memory that "gk.py" consumed increases linearly with time. memory that "gnk.py" consumed remains constantly with time. Why does this happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into python `generator`.

Comment: What are you doing with these tuples? You do nothing with `a = tuple(sorted(sample(range(200), 100)))`. You just do that then ignore the result.

Comment: I want to generate and keep the tuples. "gk.py"(generate & keep) is the incumbent file, "gnk.py"(generate & not keep) is for comparison.

Comment: Well of course you're consuming more and more memory. You're storing more and more tuples. Expecting that to *not* consume all your memory eventually suggests you've got a bad mental model of what memory consumption means.

Comment: As @user2357112 stated, I am confused what you want. You are generating tuples and storing them. Do you expect them not to take memory? You aren't "keeping it in a file" your keeping it in memory. If you want to keep it in a file you need to write it to a file. Why do you need a bunch of random tuples in memory in an infinite loop?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. Editing...

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope I make myself clear this time.

Comment: `mprof`'s line-oriented design doesn't match well with how memory consumption actually works in computer programs, and the results are rarely meaningful. It's best ignored.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the size of the set is being constantly increased, there will be a time when it will eventually consume all memory.

An estimative (from my computer):

```
10 seconds of code running ~ 5e4 tuples saved to the set
300 seconds of code running ~ 1.5e6 tuples saved to the set

1 tuple = 100 integers ~ 400bytes

total:

1.5e6 * 400bytes = 6e8bytes = 600MB filled in 300s
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you give some advice this time, please?

Comment: For question 2, what's weird to you? The fact that "gk.py" memory consumption increases with time or that "gnk.py" memory consumption doesn't?

Comment: Never mind. I get it now. It seems the set "A" is allocated memory dynamically. That's why the memory increases.